# Dropzone.js not clickable after upload

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js, razorengine

I am trying to submit some files to Azure, it works great the first time, but when I refresh the page, the dropzone isn't clickable anymore. I am using a button to trigger the upload.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    url: "/EntregaArchivo/Subir",
    //autoDiscover: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFilesize: 20, //MB
    maxFiles: 5,
    //acceptedFiles: "image/*, application/pdf, .doc, .docx",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remover',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Archivo es mas grande que 20MB',
    // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    error: function (file, msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    init: function() {
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("#btnUpload")
        dropzone = this; // closure

        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            dropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
        });
        this.on("complete", function (data) {
            //var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
            $("#TextoInicio").load('@(Url.Action("ArchivosActuales", "EntregaArchivo"))');
        });
    }
};
```

The previous jQuery is in a cshtml view, that view contains a partial view which has the dropzone(and button) and a list of the files.

Thanks a lot in advance for everyone who participates in helping me

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you should try to rename your variable `dropzone` in your `init` function. Maybe there is an issue, because of the name of the `Dropzone` library. I could not test it, but that maybe can the problem.

Comment: @dns_nx I tried that, but still it doesnt work. Thanks